# How to prints prime numbers in each list (five numbers each line) from the doubly linked list c#

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list

How can I display a prime number from a doubly-linked list from a text file?

```
 public void middleOfList()
        {

            if (head == null) ;
            if (head.next == null || head.next.next == null) ;


            Node slow = head, fast = head.next.next;

            // iterate till the middle element
            while (fast != null && fast.next != null)
            {
                slow = slow.next;//Add New nodeto the middle of the linked list.
                fast = fast.next.next; //Add new node to the last of the linked list.
            }


            if (fast != null) slow = slow.next;

            Console.WriteLine("The Middle number of list is: " + slow.data);
        } 

    }
```

Comment: It's better to put the development language in a tag instead of the title because the questions are filtered by tag and that way your question can get better exposure to the right people.

Comment: What are you expecting those empty `if` statements to do?  They are followed by a semicolon `;` and no code block so, I'm confused as to what you intended that code to do.

Comment: Please add more details, cause there are couple of wordings that makes your question confusing. Method name you have used is middleOfList, you mentioned prime number, text file, and double linked list. How they are related?

Comment: Guys i am new for C# my question is how can I print prime number e.g I have three text file(file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt) with integer 1 to 21.I already print length of number and middle number from the list so now i want to print prime number from that txt file.